# How to make a field uneditable

Tags: c#, adobe, livecycle

I have a form with some 5 text fields. Firstly I am filling out the form in workspace and assigning it to some other person in the workflow. My requirement is that person to whom i have assigned the form should not be able to edit the form data say ONLY three particular fields. How can i achieve the same?
I want to lock those particular fields and it should not be editable.

Answer (score 1):

I made this handy deal: parse your `xfa form` `xml` through this:

```
    private string MakeReadOnly(string xml) 
    {
        string formName = GetFormName(xml);

        return @"
ProcessAllFields(xfa.form." + formName + @");

function ProcessAllFields(oNode) {
    if (oNode.className == 'exclGroup' || oNode.className == 'subform'  || oNode.className == 'subformSet' || oNode.className == 'area') { 
    for (var i = 0; i < oNode.nodes.length; i++) {
            var oChildNode = oNode.nodes.item(i); ProcessAllFields(oChildNode);
        }
    } else if (oNode.className == 'field') {
        oNode.access = 'readOnly'
    }
}";
    }

    private string GetFormName(string xml)
    {
        string formName = string.Empty;
        int subFormStart = xml.IndexOf("<subform", 0);
        if (subFormStart > -1)
        {
            int nameTagStart = xml.IndexOf("name", subFormStart);
            int nameStart = xml.IndexOf("\"", nameTagStart);
            int nameEnd = xml.IndexOf("\"", nameStart + 1);

            formName = xml.Substring(nameStart + 1, (nameEnd - nameStart) - 1);
        }

        return formName;
    }
```

Then call it like this:

```
            PdfAction readOnlyAction = PdfAction
                .JavaScript(MakeReadOnly(xfa.DomDocument.InnerXml), stamper.Writer);
            stamper.Writer.AddJavaScript(readOnlyAction);
```

Call it right before:

```
            stamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;

            stamper.Close();
            reader.Close();
```

And there you go. Read-only XFA fields!

Answer (score 0):

Each field in XFA based forms has an access property that can be set on any event.  The access property can be set to one of the following items:

```
"open|protected|readOnly|nonInteractive"
```

For example, to set a TextField called "City" contained in subform "AddressSubform", you can set the access property the following way to make it uneditable:

```
AddressSubform.City.access = "readOnly";
```

This JavaScript code snippet needs to be triggered on an event like the click of a button, the exit of a field or on form initialize if the form is in a specific form-state.

In the use case you have mentioned, you need to keep track of who is filling out the form. In general (best practice), this is tracked by setting a form-state variable in the LiveCycle forms. Hence, when you are done with the form in workspace, you need to make sure that the form-state is set to another value. Once the other user receives the form, you can check the new form-state on the initialize event of the form and set these fields as indicated in the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a flag in your data to indicate if the fields need to be locked or not. You need to set the flag before the form rendering takes place. You can use `setValue` service for this. You can then simply add `initialize` scripts to your the fields you'd like to make read only by checking the flag in the Data.

```
var flag = xfa.resolveNode("xfa.datasets.data.Root.config.flag").value;

if(flag == "lock"){
    this.access = "readOnly";
} else {
    this.access = "";
}
```

Note that the above code assumes you your data XML is structured as following.

```
<Root>
    <config>
        <flag>lock</flag>
    </config>
    <restOfData>
    ...
    </restOfData>
</Root>
```